# what are limitations of shallow clone

Tags: git

In our organization where we are trying to introduce Git, we have now a problem related to Git behavior with respect to binary files.
Our projects will have a good mix of binary and text type files and a typical size could be 1 GB. Our fear is that after few years a full clone would become too big and cause performance and disk space issues. 
One of the environment that would migrate to Git have their SW currently on a system called TCM. The total size of repositories with versions of 7-10 years is 2 TB.
Another environment on ClearCase has around 7-8 years data of around 1 TB.
With Git not storing in deltas which will particularly affect binary files, a situation post 5+ years is causing concern to our users.
Shallow clone feature would have been ideal. But the docu says this "A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.". A cursory check on shallow clones would show that it works fine, but definitely there are known use-cases where it wont work, hence document
Is there a known list of use-cases where this wont work?

Comment: Update: Since git V1.9, most limitations of shallow clones have been resolved.

Comment: Git 2.5 (Q2 2015) supports a single fetch commit! I have edited my answer below, now referencing "[Pull a specific commit from a remote git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309)".

Comment: VTC as unclear. The docs give a full summary of what it can't do. A "list of use-cases" is whatever you can imagine that uses those operations. Which is an infinite set, thus impossible to put into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would urge you to store binary files in a dedicated repository, easy to scale and easy to clean up: an artifact repo like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).
You have other alternatives in "[How to handle a large git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855926/how-to-handle-a-large-git-repository/12855986#12855986)".

Trying to keep everything in Git, using it in some unnatural way, will always result in more trouble that is is worth: it is a *source* control tool. You might as well use it for what it is good for.

That being said, <del>a shallow clone doesn't support push (or, at least, it is dangerous: see "[Why can't I push from a shallow clone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900103/why-cant-i-push-from-a-shallow-clone)").</del>
For read-only purpose, a simple [`git archive`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) would be enough, as mentioned in "[not understanding git shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992611/not-understanding-git-shallow-clone)".

Updates 2015:

- actually, you now can use a shallow clone for push/pull, see "[Is `git clone --depth 1` (shallow clone) more useful than it makes out?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309)"
- you can (with Git 2.5+) even fetch a single commit. See "[Pull a specific commit from a remote git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701724/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

[Git Annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) solves the "big-binary-files in/near git" problem quite beautifully, as well.